# sampling from regular pandas series using irregular DatetimeIndex and fill method

Tags: pandas, indexing, time-series, interpolation, sampling

I have a regular time series and a DatetimeIndex of irregular dates. I would like to obtain a new irregular time series where the irregular times are filled from the regular one using one of the standard methods ("ffill" is the one I am after).

```
import pandas as pd

times = pd.date_range(start="2000-01-01 00:00", periods = 12, freq="H")
df = pd.DataFrame({"val":np.arange(12)},index=times)

newtimes = pd.DatetimeIndex(["2000-01-01 02:13","2000-01-01 03:00"])
print(df.val.loc[newtimes])
```

produces a warning and this:

```
2000-01-01 02:13:00    NaN
2000-01-01 03:00:00    3.0
```

whereas the backfill answer I would like is this:

```
2000-01-01 02:13:00    2.0
2000-01-01 03:00:00    3.0
```

Seems like a common use case but couldn't find the answer. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want `df.val.loc[newtimes.floor('H')]`? because there is a warning anyway `Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise KeyError in the future`

Comment: Edited to mention the warning. I was expecting an answer that used `method='ffill'` but this this seems to work so feel free to post it. It can be extended to an irregular source using:
`df_irreg.resample('1H').ffill().val.loc[newtimes.floor('H')]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `2000-01-01 02:13:00` as index in the output instead of `2000-01-01 02:00:00`, I think you need reindex timeseries by minute and `ffill` and `loc` by `newtimes`

```
df.asfreq(freq='T', method='ffill').val.loc[newtimes]

Out[1538]:
2000-01-01 02:13:00    2
2000-01-01 03:00:00    3
Name: val, dtype: int32
```